# Check if element has a specific class and open bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How do I check if a element has a specific class and open then a modal?

HTML Code:

```
<ul>
<li class="class-one class-two has-error">Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

If the `<li>` has the class `has-error` then a Bootstrap modal should open:

```
<div id="has-error" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    ERROR!
  </div>
</div>
```

I definitely need a script to check if the class exists and to fire the modal, but i have no idea how to start.

Comment: `if($(element).hasClass('className')){ // do your  stuff }`

Comment: How to fire the modal?

Comment: Not hard to search for both issues .... read bootstrap docs to see how to open modal and a search for *"jQuery has class"* will provide lots of results...including the api docs

Comment: *"I definitely need a script"* ... Stackoverflow is neither a free code writing service nor a *"how to"* tutorial service. Take some time to read through [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// You need to describe the situation, but if it occurs on page load, use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { // When page finished loading
  if ( $('.has-error').length ) { // if there is an DOM that has class has-error
     $('#has-error').modal('show'); // Show Modal
  }
});
```

Comment: I have form and clicking on "Submit" courses, that some checkboxes text marked in red (added by the class "has-error", if they are not checked. I want to check if the class, whcih courses the red color, exits and fire a modal

Comment: I think i need to add the "onclick" function

Comment: Nobody got a idea?    :-(

Comment: Please have a read of boostrap modal, and how to activate it with jQuery. I think your knowledge on the things you are attempting is severely lacking.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/